# Frustration at a new company

Tags: work-environment, technology, working-conditions

I saw someone experiencing a similar (but not quite the same) frustrations to me on here and I saw the replies were very helpful and insightful, and I'm hoping you could help me too.

I worked in a company for 10 years, toward the end, I worked as a reporting analyst. I loved (most) of the people there with really forward thinking people, but it became very high demanding and also fast-paced - which I didn't mind on it's own but I didn't have time to do everything, with continuous instability/worry about future of everyone's roles (they had a couple of re-structures and moving around people for few years, which I believe is still going on) causing me to have time off for stress.

Considering the above, I decided it was the time for me to move on. I got a new role in a different company, which is a different industry but at high level, he purpose of my role is effectively the same. Report on how well that certain sector of the company is doing.

Now, here is my frustration. It's been a couple of month now, and the methods used by this new company to do effectively the same work is... very inefficient. The method used compared to my old role lack structure and the software (which they have a lot of, but random variety of it used through out when the source of the data is the same), and it's almost as though I've carried on with my old role but the technology has gone back in time. Something (the equivalent task in the previous role) that took 15 minutes to do takes couple of hours here, it's very manual and very had for someone outside of the business to get to grips with as in-depth knowledge of the industry is needed with little amendments needed in the data (manually of course).

The previous company did have a similar situation 6,7 years ago, but even then they were still ahead of this company, and I know it's going to take a drastic re-building of the whole work to change this.

I've started thinking about leaving as I feel I am starting to feel very unsuitable for the role, which I had before but because I know things could be ran better. But am I being a spoilt brat? I like the people but at the end of the day they're not going to be there forever (and could argue is part of the problem why things are done like this).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: It's up to you what you decide. Leaving is always option (but make sure you don't run into same problem again in new company.. you cannot keep quitting forever). You can also try to improve your new organization. But it will take considerable time and first you have to earn their respect. They won't start listening to a new hire and taking orders from him.

Comment: Statements like "give me advice" or "what should I do?" or "am I being a spoiled brat?" are going to be hard to answer within the structure of Stack Exchange. If you can clearly state a goal, ask a specific question, and be clear on what you're looking for, we will be better situated to help you.

Comment: Sounds like you have an excellent opportunity to improve things at this new organization and prove your value. You already know how things can be better. Are you sure you want to throw that away?

Comment: Both VarunAgw's and SethR's comments are on the spot. Why not make contributions to improve the new organzition?

Answer (score 7):

Do what anyone else would do in your place.

Start sand-boxing a new process.  Pick something up that's taking a long time, and work on getting that process slicker and more efficient.  Demonstrate this, try to get it adopted by the rest of the team.

If you give up and move on, it's unlikely that you'll find something that exactly meets your needs and you'll go around in a circle, and find it progressively harder to explain why you're moving jobs.

Comment: I have to disagree about making it harder to explain moving jobs. From what I've seen, people typically stay 2-3 years then move on. If you fall in that time frame, you don't have to explain why you're moving on as much as job hopping every 3 months.

Comment: @Dan, the OP has been in this job "a couple of months", though, not 2-3 years.